# How to write a bash script that runs a customized program?

Tags: bash

Here is an example for my customized program which is executed as:

```
./TestVariance.exe 2 100 10 .9
```

I want to write a bash script that runs it several times while changing the second argument each time. After searching some answers on SO, I come up with a script like

```
#!/bin/bash
let d=2
let s=10
let q=9/10
for i in 'seq 100 100 1000'
do 
    ./TestVariance.exe $d $i $s $q;
done
```

But it seems that the script only call `TestVariance.exe` without passing any arguments. I wonder what's wrong with my script?

BTW, is there any advice for vscode extensions on bash script?

Comment: If you want to provide the list of values for `i` only literally (and not via parameter), you would write `for i in {100..1000..100}`.

Comment: let q=9/10 will result in q=0. Based on your initial sample I expect you wanted 0.9.

You don't actually need to use 'let' when setting variables, so you could simply use 'q=0.9' or look at tools like bc if you really need to do floating point math.

Comment: @tjm3772 you are right. But when I put q=0.9, the script just tells me it is a `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".9")`. I wonder how to overcome this. **Edit**: I come to realized that I can just put .9 as plain text, now it runs well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
`seq 100 100 1000`
```

`'seq 100 100 1000'` is literal.

Comment: You can replace backticks by bash command substitution: `$(seq 100 100 1000)`. Or you can replace the whole `seq` subprocess by bash range: `{100..1000..100}`.

Comment: Indeed, I thought it was something more complex...

Comment: That's very subtle for me, before I've only used ` in markdown. Thank you very much.